# IdentityServer SSO with oidc and saml(Azure AD)

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, asp.net-authorization, sustainsys-saml2

Current state:

- ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - BoatsApp
- ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - CarsApp
- ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app - Duende Identity Server - IdS

I'm able to achieve Single Sign-On with use of oidc.

Next, on IdS I have added Saml2 authenication(Sustainsys.Saml2) feature - that part works with Azure AD single sign-on.

It's workflow:

Log in with Saml => redirect to MS add email 'page' => redirect to Azure AD company login page => redirect back to localhost with SamlResponse etc.

[Just for information: I'm able to valid (SamlREponse)SAML Assertion, and get Claims from Azure.
On ExternalLogin/Callback in returnUrl I get something like "/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=..."]

The goal of all of this is to create Single-Sign-On server for all applications in a company.

I'm not sure what next, tbh.

The reason is that on response from IdS I would like to have JWT Token, which for oidc works well, but what about SAML?

What am I missing? Is this the right way to do this? What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: SAML ist broken by design. Better use ODIC only. That way all your apps only gave to support one kind of SSO login. Do you want to connect to multiple different IdPs?

Comment: unfortunately it's not my choice...

Comment: You could use dex to connect to different IdPs. That way your apps only have to support OIDC. However SAML does not support refresh tokens, so you would have to use longer lived tokens. Or you use Auth0 or sth similar. Same Advantage: you don't have to care about SAML but just implement OIDC.